# CSS Help for top menu and table with 2 columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a table like in the picture below. 
[image]

I'm using bootstrap. Here is the example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" style="margin-left: 20px;">123 Main Street - Big Blue</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <p style="margin-right: 50px;">
          June 07, 2018 <br />
          57 F
        </p>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
          Dawn Rabideau 2-100
          <br />
          Lonnie Robinson (Pinoy Arts) T-100
          <br />
          Pro Wrestling Hall of Fame A-101
          <br />
          Michael Chapman T-101
          <br />
          Ted Klopf 2-717
          <br />
          Harvest Ministries T-1100 Suite
          <br />
           Ricci Consulting, LLC T-608
          <br />
          North Texas Home Therapy Professionals T-500B
          <br />
          Terry Thompson T-623
          <br />
          Substance Abuse Testing Solutions T-830
          <br />

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
          Melons and Cuties T-104
          <br />
          Amy Janjgava 2-701
          <br />
          Dexter Learning T-200
          <br />
          Mary Amanda Beaver Counseling Services T-825
          <br />
          Marsha Wright Reeves T-610
          <br />
          Nosidrah Enterprises T-500A
          <br />
          B Strong Consulting DBA Court on Blue T-105
          <br />
          Marshall Hall T-532
          <br />
          American Financial Network, Inc T-102
          <br />
          The EDI Exchange T-600
          <br />

        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm not good using CSS. How can I make my 2 columns inside the row more similar to the picture? Also my nav top bar is not very well formatted. Is there a way to format the top nav menu?

Thanks

Comment: Do like `<table><thead><tr><th>Table Head</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table>` or learn CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap you can follow the [bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) for responsive grids on your page.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="background: url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/background.jpg')">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">123 Main Street - Big Blue</a>
      <div>
       <span class="navbar-text">
           June 07, 2018 <br />
           57 F
       </span>
   </div>
</nav>    
<div class="container-flex">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
          Alambic Invesment Management
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
          1905
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
          MWA Architects
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
          1720
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To format the `navbar` you can always use css.

Comment: Thank you. It was what I was looking for. Any idea which property I should use for the CSS to make that style?

Comment: It depends on the element you want to add a style to and you haven't mentioned what do you want to do to your navbar

Comment: Sorry. I was trying to add a background image like in the picture with a name in the left size (big font) and today's date and local weather in the right side.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a background image for navbar